# Automatic inverse for Lambert’s Azimuthal Equal-Area Projection

Tags: equation-solving, inverse, geodesy, projection

I’m interested in finding closed-form inverses for map projection equations in general (of course, this is not always possible). I’m hoping Mathematica can help me with some of the trickier ones.

As a **practice run**, I thought I would try and use Mathematica to invert [Lambert’s Azimuthal Equal-Area Projection](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertAzimuthalEqual-AreaProjection.html).  There are of course closed-form inverse equations on MathWorld, but I’m wondering how I would go about finding these using Mathematica.

I’ve tried using `Solve` and `Reduce`, for example:

```
k = Sqrt[2/(1 + s1 Sin[y] + c1 Cos[y] Cos[x])]
Solve[{u, v} == {
  k Cos[y] Sin[x], 
  k (c1 Sin[y] - s1 Cos[y] Cos[x])
}, {x, y}]
```

But no luck so far.  Perhaps I need to specify more constraints?

For example, I know that the longitude and latitude (`x` and `y` above) have:

```
-π ≤ x ≤ π
-π/2 ≤ y ≤ π/2
```

I wonder if eliminating variables might also help the solving routines.

Comment: Have you seen the help pages for [`Latitude`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Latitude.html) and `Longitude`?  A (minor modification of an) example from that page exhibits an unprojection: `Through[{Latitude, Longitude}[GeoGridPosition[{-0.12605573,-0.0464294, 0}, "LambertConformalConic"]]]`.

Comment: I'm interested in automatically finding closed-form inverse formulæ, given arbitrary forward projection equations, so I'm not sure that really helps me. But thanks anyway!

Comment: I've clarified the wording of the question a bit, so it's clear what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: In most cases there's no such thing as closed-form inverse formulae for non-spherical datums, so I presume you mean to apply these equations only to spheres.  See http://pubs.usgs.gov/pp/1395/report.pdf for details. Moreover, only the simpler projections have closed forms, so the problem does not generally have a solution.

Comment: Yes, I’m only dealing with spheres, so that should simplify things. I know there is no general solution, but I'd like to know how to solve the simplest ones using Mathematica. Lambert’s azimuthal equal-area seems relatively simple, yet as you can see I’ve failed so far to find the (already known) result using `Solve` or `Reduce`.